# Media, missing local video thumbnails

Tags: views, media, files, display-suite

We have local stored video that we display using the media module and Video in field views.

In a view with several videos only a few gets a thumbnail image representing the video. This configuration:

Controls: visible
Autoplay: nej
Loop: nej
Muted: nej
Size: 100% x 225
Multiple files: tags
Field template: Drupal default

With Firefox we got 90 % of the videos with image preview and with Chromium 50 %.